# Use excel power query to expose SQL server data with restricted access to user data

Tags: powerquery, m

we are using Excel's Power Query (Get & Transform) to process test measurement data files we have collected for our respective clients.

Once it is processed the data is transferred to and from a local SQL server instance (using excel VBA to insert and power query to retrieve).

I would like to expose this database to our clients directly by providing a  workbook template (with queries for downstream processing) rather than creating csv files and emailing them with graphical reports at regular intervals.

My question is, in general terms, how can I design/configure the database to restrict access to data owned by a specific client? Or otherwise opinions on the simplest path to providing external data access would be appreciated.

Comment: Within Excel/PQ, all you could do is setup queries that only pull data for that specific customer and then lock the workbook so the queries can be refreshed but not edited. Mind you this isn't any kind of real security, as bypassing  "security" in an Excel file is trivial for those so inclined. I think true security would involve something like implementing a Row Level Security scheme on SQL Server, but that has little to do with PQ/Excel.

Comment: Thanks Wedge, I agree it would be ideal to implement the security in Excel but as you say it's not great.